# Can swift generics be used inside class with generics

Tags: swift, generics

I have a protocol call `Decodable`:

```
public protocol Decodable {
    typealias DecodedType = Self
    static func decode(e: Extractor) -> DecodedType?
}
```

I have a function `decode`:

```
public func decode<T: Decodable where T.DecodedType == T>(object: AnyObject) -> T? {
```

Also, I have a class `RestApiResponseParser`

```
class RestApiResponseParser<T where T:Decodable> {
    private func createServerModels(response: ServerResponse) -> Result<T> {
        var parsingError:NSError?
        let link: T? = decode(response)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and `typealias ServerResponse = [String: AnyObject]`
which I try to call as:

```
let responseParser = RestApiResponseParser<MyModel>(responseData: inputObject as! NSData)
let processError = responseParser.processResponseData()
```

Unfortunately, I get compile time error:

[image]

Does it mean, I can't use generic function in generic class?

Comment: Is `ServerResponse` a struct? If so, then it is not an `AnyObject` and that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: @RomanSausarnes sorry for confusion: `typealias ServerResponse = [String: AnyObject]`

Comment: @user1284151 That is a struct, dictionaries are structs

Comment: @Kametrixom this one compiles: `let x:MyModel? = decode(["string":2])`. I also tried to cast to NSDictionary

Comment: When you pass a dictionary to a function that takes `AnyObject` it gets automatically bridged to an NSDictionary, that's why that works

Comment: @Kametrixom so why `decode(response as NSDictionary)` doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a generic function in a generic class. Your problem is that you are passing a `[String: AnyObject]` dictionary (which is a struct, and not an `AnyObject`) into a function that is expecting an `AnyObject`. It looks like you need to extract the `AnyObject` from the dictionary using its key:

```
if let object = response["<insert your key here>"] {
    decode(object)
}
```

Another approach would be to cast your `ServerResponse` to an `NSDictionary` which is a class, and can therefore be passed as an `AnyObject`:

```
let link: T? = decode(response as NSDictionary)
```

And btw, the bridging between `Dictionary` and `NSDictionary` is not as "seemless" as Apple claims - I have run into instances like this where I can't figure out why Swift isn't able to automatically bridge them for me, and when I have to be explicit. There are inconsistencies like the one that you noted. Your function will take a `Dictionary` as an argument in once place, but not another, without a clear rationale for why. Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that you are using a `typealias`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `let x:MyModel? = decode(["string":2])` doesn't generate that error

Comment: In some instances, Swift can convert a dictionary to an `NSDictionary` - which is a class (not a struct) - behind the scenes. Sometimes you can cast to `NSDictionary` manually. See my edited answer.

Comment: still doesn't compile with error: Cannot invoke decode with type (NSDictionary)